# call external function inside onclick button in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, onclick

My goal is print strings and for each one print a button too. This button needs a onclick="add()".

```
+"<button onclick=add("+carrello[i].nome+","+carrello[i].quantita+");>+</button>"+
```

I have problem calling external function inside a read() function. I need to declare a button that use onclick function and call add() but when I run the code noting happen.
[image: the problem image]

```js
function add(nome, prezzo)
{
  var exist = 0;
  var prodotto = new Object();
  prodotto.nome=nome;
  prodotto.costo=prezzo;
  prodotto.quantita=1;

  for (i = 0; i < carrello.length; i++)
  {
    if(carrello[i].nome==prodotto.nome)
    {
      //esiste già
      exist = 1;
      carrello[i].quantita=carrello[i].quantita+1;
      $(event.target).closest('tr').find('.qty').html(" (x"+carrello[i].quantita+")");
    }
  }
 if(exist == 0)
  {
    $(event.target).closest('tr').find('.qty').html(" (x1)");
    carrello.push(prodotto);
  }

  read();
}


function read()
{
  var totale = 0;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < carrello.length; i++)
  {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += carrello[i].nome+"x"+carrello[i].quantita+" <button onclick=add("+carrello[i].nome+","+carrello[i].quantita+");>+</button>"+"<br>";
          //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ;
          var x = document.createElement("HR");
          document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(x);
          document.getElementById("ordine").value = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
          totale = totale + carrello[i].costo * carrello[i].quantita;
          document.getElementById("totale").innerHTML = "Totale: "+totale+"€";
      }
      if(carrello.length==0)
      {
        totale = 0;
        document.getElementById("totale").innerHTML = "";
      }
        document.getElementById("tot").value = totale;
}
```

Comment: From what you've provided, none of those function are ever called. I've added your code into a runnable snippet. Please edit it to reflect a [mcve]

Comment: Is useless reproduce the entire algorithm im trying only to know how call function inside a onclick inside another function.

Comment: Well, if we don't have a reproductible example, it is useless to try and help you with your problem. You have to understand that we cannot intuitively know what is going on. You didn't seams to specify the actual error your were getting, just _nothing is happening_. There is a debugging job that, you should have done, and without a proper example, we cannot do either.

Comment: You *maybe/probably* want `" <button onclick='add(" .. ");'>+</button>"` - but that's just a guess.  Why not add a delegated event handler instead of antiquated `onclick=`?  But then `nome` looks like it might be "name" so will need to be in quotes itself in-case there are spaces in the name.

Comment: Have a read of [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal code to reproduce the issue* - what exactly *is* the issue?   Is it using `innerHTML +=` with a button?  Then you don't need all that other code.  Is it that `nome` has a space in and it's breaking your HTML?  Then you don't need all that other code, but you do need an example of `nome`.   We don't want "the entire algorithm`, just *enough* to demonstrate the problem without having to guess it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: drop JQuery and writing raw HTML as strings but use the browser native APIs instead

You can use `document.createElement` to create an element object and then work on that within JavaScript directly. Something like:

```js
const button = document.createElement('button')
// now you have a basic button element that you can insert or manipulate however you like
// add the `onClick` callback
button.onClick = () => add(...yourParams)
```

if you have to repeat something like this multiple times, wrap it into a helper function, eg.

```js
function makeButton({nome, quantita}) {
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  button.onClick = () => add(nome, quantita)
  return button
}
```

Now you could for example use this directly whith `carrello.map(makeButton)` and presto! you'll have an array of buttons ready to be added to the dom. this way you don't have to do all the `for`-looping and have code that is both readable and maintainable.

All the raw HTML writing is almost impossible to maintain and debug and JQuery lessens your level of controle while often giving a false sense of maintainability.
Creating, manipulating and managing elements as JS-object will give you a deeper understanding of their functionality (and the actual functionality of your code) and give you a sense of structure instead of floating strings to be interpreted by the browser.